Google AdManager API - YieldGroupService - YieldAdSource
I'm using Google Ad Manager API from NodeJS. I need to create a Yield Group by specifying an array of YieldAdSource. The problem is that this entity has a value called displaySettings. But, Google Ad Manager API doesn't specify how to use it. The documentation is a bit strange.
If anyone knows this documentation better, please tell me how I can do this. I'm leaving the current code and the link to the documentation below. Thanks.
const res = await yieldGroupService.updateYieldGroups({
  yieldGroups: [{
    ...
    adSources: partners.map((partner) => ({
      ...
      displaySettings:    {
        openBiddingSettings: {
          yieldIntegrationType: 'OPEN_BIDDING'  
        }
      }
    }))
  }]
});

That gives an error because it says that displaySettings is not correct.
Doc:
https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v202405/YieldGroupService.YieldAdSource
